# Right way to transform data after fetching it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I fetch the countries from the endpoint, but in order to display data in the desired form, I transform it with the RxJS map operator, where I calculate the length of the products array and total expenses with `reduce()` method. This code is working perfectly fine, but the problem is I don't know if this is the right way to do the transformation. So to sum up my confusion, I have the following questions:

```
getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
return this.http.get<responseCountry[]>(this.countriesUrl).pipe(
  map((countries: responseCountry[]) =>
    countries.map((country: responseCountry): Country => {

      const transformedCountryData: Country = {
        name: country.name,
        quantity_of_products: country.products.length,
        totalExpense: this.calculateTotalExpenses(
          country.products
        ),
      };
      return transformedCountryData;
    })
  )
);
}

calculateTotalExpenses(products: Product[]): number {
const initialValue = 0;

const totalExpense: number = products.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => {
    return (
      previousValue +
      currentValue.price * currentValue.quantity_for_month
    );
  },
  initialValue
);

return totalExpense;
}
```

1. Maybe it is a better way to create and use `Country Class` instead of an `interface`, as I would use it both for type-checking, plus I could move the `calculateTotalExpenses()` method to that class and the transformation would take place inside the class instead of service. Am I correct? Is there any better solution?
2. Be prepared, here I expose my deep knowledge gap:) When I transform data as I do, what if `calculateTotalExpenses()` method which uses `.reduce()` give me the result a little bit later (maybe due to lots of products), doesn't it cause `totalExpense` property to be `undefined` or something?
3. Maybe I should do this transformation on the backend and deliver ready properties? Is it bad practice to do this kind of data transformation on the front end?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understood why you need to call map twice, since the map is a array function that transforms Array<A> into Array<B>

Comment: The first `map` is an rxjs operator that transforms the observable value. This still gives you a parameter of type `responseCountry[]`, where you still need to map each element. @Lasha I think the code is good. Keep using observables in order to use `| async` in the component templates. I'd only drop the excessive type specifiers to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your 3 point :

> This is the best practice to follow, we should always avoid such calculations in front end. Your back end API should return you the transformed data

2 point :

> No, this will never happen unless there is null/undefined in data itself or some calculation mistake. You are returning an `Observable` and you will use `subscribe` or `async` `pipe` to consume it. Whenever the `subscription` will happen, the `pipe` operator will take care of it.

3 point :

> As per my knowledge, it's better to use interface.